# Windows Batch: Call after CMD finishes

Tags: batch-file, windows-10, xcopy

I have Windows 10 and inside of my batch file I do the following:

```
start cmd /k "Build_x1.bat"
start cmd /k "Build_x2.bat"
start cmd /k "Build_x3.bat"
...
start cmd /k "Build_xN.bat"
```

The reason that I have it as `start cmd` is because I want it to open in a new window; they all finish at different times and in their own window, they output their own warnings and errors of files they are compiling. As they finish, they produce a .adb file to my directory. In this same script, I want to xcopy the *.adb into a different directory. The problem I am running into is that I don't know how to start the xcopy only after all of the above cmd's finish in their own window.  So I want:

```
start cmd /k "Build_x1.bat"
start cmd /k "Build_x2.bat"
start cmd /k "Build_x3.bat"
...
start cmd /k "Build_xN.bat"

xcopy /s/y *.adb "C:\*some directory*"
```

but xcopy only after all of the above `start cmd` have finished.  Any thoughts on how I could achieve this?  I've tried a few methods but all have failed and prematurely try to copy files without them being ready.

Comment: `(start "" cmd /C "Build_x1.bat" & start "" cmd /C "Build_x.bat" & ...) | pause`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start them with a title and check for their windows. Loop until they all are finished:

```
start "MyTitle" cmd /c "Build_x1.bat"
start "MyTitle" cmd /c "Build_x2.bat"
start "MyTitle" cmd /c "Build_x3.bat"
...
start "MyTitle" cmd /c "Build_xN.bat"
:loop
timeout 1
tasklist /fi "WindowTitle eq MyTitle" |find "cmd.exe" && goto :loop
echo all of them are finished
```

PS: if those batch file names are like in your example, you can start them with:

```
for /l %%i in (1,1,%n%) do start "MyTitle" cmd /c "Build_x%%i.bat"
```

NOTE: `cmd /k` keeps the windows open, so you will have to manually close each of them.

Comment: I was going to.do exactly this but it seemed like op wanted to retain the `stderr` and `stdout` of each batch in the separate windows, hence my silly answer.

Comment: You might want to also check for windowtitle eq Administrator: MyTitle.

Comment: @avery_larry no need for that.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Are you sure?  I have quite a few scripts that run this way and I have not yet found a concrete reason why a window title will or will not have the Administrator: prefix (other than it never does without being run as administrator).  Particularly when a given cmd file may be called directly or from the task scheduler.  I had to modify a bunch of my scripts to accommodate the possibility that the Administrator: prefix may or may not exist.

Comment: @avery_larry. Yes I am sure. try `tasklist /v | find "MyTitle"`

Comment: @GerhardBarnard `tasklist /fi ...` is *much* faster than `tasklist /v |find...`, but yes, it works too. (in fact, two `tasklist /fi ...` (for with and without "Admin") is still a lot faster)

Comment: @stephan. I did not even notice the difference between the 2. But I have a Asus Rog Strix scar 3 so maybe my processing is just too advanced `:p` anyway I was just saying that Admin is not required. There are other ways.

Answer (score 0):

Starting the commands like you do initiates them in a different window and you release control of it from the parent. So few options, You could initiate them all at once using `start /b` which will start them all separately, but in the same window, but log their `stdout` and `stderr` to file (one per batch file) then the copy can be initiated after the batch is completed:

```
@echo off
set "list=Build_x1.bat Build_x2.bat Build_x3.bat Build_xN.bat
for %%I in (%list%) do start "" /b "%%I">>"%%~nI.log" >2%1
xcopy /s/y *.adb "C:\*some directory*"
```

if you want to see the results of each files output at the end of the run:

```
@echo off
set "list=Build_x1.bat Build_x2.bat Build_x3.bat Build_xN.bat
for %%I in (%list%) do (
    echo **** Log for %%~I *** >>"%%~nI.log"
    start "" /b "%%I.bat">>"%%~nI.log" >2%1
)
xcopy /s/y *.adb "C:\*some directory*"
type Build Build*.log
```

or to see them all in independent windows:

```
@echo off
set "list=Build_x1.bat Build_x2.bat Build_x3.bat Build_xN.bat
for %%I in (%list%) do start "" /b "%%I.bat">>"%%~nI.log" >2%1
xcopy /s/y *.adb "C:\*some directory*"
for %%I in (%list%) do start "%%~nI" cmd /k type "%%~nI.log"
```